# how to accommodate elements in html (5x5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

You need to accommodate 25 images in the following way

[image: example]

the idea is that it is a responsive "container", some help or example for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use col-2 in all elements and offset-1 in both edges (per row)

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-2 offset-1'></div>
        <div class='col-2'></div>
        <div class='col-2'></div>
        <div class='col-2'></div>
        <div class='col-2'></div>
    </div>

    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

[image: grid demo]

Example uses Bootstrap 4